# Ampersand after multicolumn?

Tags: tables

I am not sure I understand the rules re-placing an ampersand after a multicolumn command in a tabular environment.

Here is a simple example that should demonstrate the different behavior, with and without an
ampersand

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{red!20}{green!20}
\begin{tabular}{*6{|l}}
\hline
 baseline & A & B & C & D & E \\\hline
 with & B & C & \multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns} &  B \\ \hline
 without & B & C & \multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns} B \\ \hline
 with & B & \multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns}& B \\ \hline
 without & B & \multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns} B \\ \hline
 with & \multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns} & B\\ \hline
 without & \multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns} B\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output is this[image]. What's going on?

Comment: For instance, in last row, without the &,  the "B" is still in B column , if you change this row by  `without & \multicolumn2{c|}{x} xxxxxxxxxx\\ \hline` you will see more clearly that the multicolumn have to share the space with the following text.

Answer (score 1):

For technical reasons the final argument of `\multicolumn` isn't really used to delimit the cell so text following it is part of the same table cell

```
\multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns} B
```

is essentially

```
\multicolumn2{c}{two-columns \vline B}
```

but

```
\multicolumn2{c|}{two-columns}& B
```

B is in the next cell.

Comment: Wow! Does this mean I can makedo without the curly brackets around the argument?
`\multicolumn2{c|}my text` if I do just above this `\def\vline\relax`?

Comment: @YossiGil no it will bite you, also no need for the redef if vline, just don't use the `|` in the second argument. best to always brace all teh arguments so `{2}` not 2 and `{my text}`